# Hacked Eth Account - What do I do with my staked tokens?

Tags: metamask, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, security

Unfortunately my Metamask wallet was hacked today on the Metamask app which I'm devasted about. I tried connecting Pancake Swap to it and it popped up asking for my words which I stupidly gave. The Eth wallet was immediately emptied which was several thousand. I have stakes in certain coins and really don't know what to do. I'm concerned if I end the stakes and transfer to a new wallet that they might disappear before I have chance to exchange them?

- Has anyone had experience with this in the past and can advise please?
- Is there no way I can recover the eth wallet? I can see the transactions of Etherscan.

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On what chain have you been staking ?

The lost eth are, unfortunately, gone - never give your seed phrase is more than a meme:/

Comment: Hi George! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! There are some services like [MyCrypto](https://blog.mycrypto.com/how-to-beat-an-ethereum-based-sweeper-and-recover-your-assets/) that allow recovering some assets from  accounts affected by sweeper bots.

Answer (score 1):

Are the staked tokens still in your custody? Normally when you stake your tokens you are basically rewarded with staked tokens that appear in your wallet as erc20 tokens. The attackers could have emptied these as well. you'll have to check on bscscan whether or not those are still in your wallets custody.

You should assume that any amount of eth you send to that wallet to make a transaction will be immediately emptied. Yet, any interaction on the blockchain on that account costs eth.. You could test out sending a small amount and hoping that you have enough of a time window to transfer staked tokens.